# Web Scraping: How do I return specific user input forms in python?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, filtering, list-comprehension, python-3.9

I'm having trouble with the forms returning an exact match for the user input.
Emphasoft developer challenge:

1. Taking a list of tax form names (ex: "Form W-2", "Form 1095-C"),
   search the website and return some informational results.
   Specifically, you must return the "Product Number", the "Title", and
   the maximum and minimum years the form is available for download.
2. Taking a tax form name (ex: "Form W-2") and a range of years
   (inclusive, 2018-2020 should fetch three years), download all PDFs
   available within that range.

```
import json import os import sys import requests from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://apps.irs.gov/app/picklist/list/priorFormPublication.html?resultsPerPage=200&sortColumn=sortOrder&indexOfFirstRow=0&{param.strip}&isDescending=false'


def get_forms(list_tax_form: list):
    """
    function to get response from iris.gov with all forms content
    :param list_tax_form: list of form names that we want to get info about
    :return: dict with form name,form title
    """
    response_list = []  # list for all responses of form names
    with requests.session() as session:
        for param in list_tax_form:
            request_params = {'value': param,
                              'criteria': 'formNumber',
                              'submitSearch': 'Find',
                              }
            res = session.get(URL, params=request_params).content
            response_list.append(res)
        return response_list


def parse_responses(list_tax_form: list):
    """
    function to get all form names, titles years from previous func return
    :param list_tax_form: list of form names that we want to get info about
    :return: list of form names, titles, years
    """
    responses = get_forms(list_tax_form)
    # empty lists to fill them with the received information for all names, years, and titles
    td_form_name, td_form_title, td_form_rev_year = [], [], []
    for response in responses:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')
        td_name = soup.find_all('td', {'class': 'LeftCellSpacer'})
        td_title = soup.find_all('td', {'class': 'MiddleCellSpacer'})
        td_rev_year = soup.find_all('td', {'class': 'EndCellSpacer'})
        td_form_name.extend(td_name)
        td_form_title.extend(td_title)
        td_form_rev_year.extend(td_rev_year)
    return td_form_name, td_form_title, td_form_rev_year


def format_responses(list_tax_form: list):
    """
    function to formate all responses for all forms we got!
    1 Task
    :param list_tax_form: list of form names that we want to get info about
    :return: formated names,links,years
    """
    td_names, td_titles, td_years = parse_responses(list_tax_form)
    names = [name.text.strip() for name in td_names]
    links = [link.find('a')['href'] for link in td_names]
    titles = [title.text.strip() for title in td_titles]
    years = [int(year.text.strip()) for year in td_years]
    set_names = set(names)
    final_dict = []
    # loop to create dictionary of result information with years of tax form available to download
    for name in set_names:
        max_year = 0
        min_year = max(years)
        dict1 = {'form_number': name}
        for index, p_name in enumerate(names):
            if p_name == name:
                if years[index] > max_year:
                    max_year = years[index]
                elif years[index] < min_year:
                    min_year = years[index]
                dict1['form_title'] = titles[index]
                dict1['max_year'] = max_year
                dict1['min_year'] = min_year
        final_dict.append(dict1)
    print(json.dumps(final_dict, indent=2))
    return names, links, years


def download_files(list_tax_form):
    """
    2 Task
    Module to download pdf files of form_name that input from user.
    :param list_tax_form: list of form names that we want to get info about
    :return: message to user of successful create file or either
    """
    names, links, years = format_responses(list_tax_form)
    form_name = input('enter form name: ')
    if form_name in names:
        print('form exists. enter years range')
        form_year1 = int(input('start year to analysis: '))
        form_year2 = int(input('end year to analysis: '))
        try:
            os.mkdir(form_name)
        except FileExistsError:
            pass
        # indecies to define names range in list of all tax form names
        r_index = names.index(form_name) # index of first form_name mention on list
        l_index = names.index(form_name) # index of last form_name mention on list
        for name in names:
            if name == form_name:
                r_index += 1
        years = years[l_index:r_index]
        if form_year1 < form_year2:
            range_years = range(form_year1, form_year2 + 1)
            for year in range_years:
                if year in years:
                    link = links[years.index(year)]
                    form_file = requests.get(link, allow_redirects=True)
                    open(f'{form_name}/{form_name}_{str(year)}.pdf', 'wb').write(form_file.content)
            print(f'files saved to {form_name}/ directory!')
    else:
        print('input correct form name!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tax_list = sys.argv[1:]  # form names
    download_files(tax_list)
```

(ex: "Form W-2" should not return "Form W-2 P")

When this file is ran, it is displaying other unrelated results.

How can I resolve this issue to display **only** specified user requests?